# Possible to use FloatingActionButton without it lingering?

Tags: java, android

I am using `FloatingActionButton` and it works without issues. Though, I want to change its behavior. I want it to behave like an `ImageButton`. When I scroll down the layout, I want it to move with the other views and disappear off-screen. I do not want it to stay on top always.

I know there is an alternative solution where I need to copy the style of `FloatingActionButton` into an `ImageView`. Though, I wanted to know if it is possible to do what I want using `FloatingActionButton` only.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want just make the button hide when scroll down and then, show when scroll up?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Vinicius Almada. No, I do not want it to hide on scroll. I want it to behave like any other view on scroll. If I scroll it keeps moving until it is off the screen.

Comment: Oh, I got it. You can make this behavior ensuring that other characteristics like elevation be the same of the other views to not show the shadow, for example. I think this is the most visible feature for the floating button original behavior.

Comment: How do I accomplish the behavior, though?

Answer (score 0):

Taking from the [Material IO](https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button) documentation, a floating action button has the following usage:

> A floating action button (FAB) performs the primary, or most common, action on a screen. It appears in front of all screen content, typically as a circular shape with an icon in its center. FABs come in three types: regular, mini, and extended.

But as you asking, you want to use it as simple view that scrolls with others on the screen. Thinking this way, you can set the most visible characteristic of a FAB less contextual, the elevation.

In your layout.xml file:

```xml
<FloatingActionButton
   app:elevation="0dp"/>
```

Comment: I have tried adding that to my FAB. It does not make any difference. The FAB button stays on top even when it is off the screen.